# Ionic - App Doesn't Work with aHrefSanitizationWhitelist

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic app and want to open a Whatsapp Chat with a specific contact when I click on a Link like this

```
ng-href="intent://send/{{contact.number}}#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end
```

But when the app compiles, it change the link to

```
unsafe:intent://....
```

So, I made some research and found this, to add some whitelist URLS to my app module.

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension|intent):/);
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension|intent):/);
```

But, when I add it to my application, it stop working on my phone.

If I run it on the serve emulator, my apps starts correctly, but when I run it on the phone, the pages stop working.

Comment: Nothing, on the Serve emulator I only get "ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" because of cordova.js

Answer (score 0):

you should add the origin you are wanting to use to your `config.xml` file

You should add this line to `config.xml`:

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="whatsapp:*"/>
```

Or if you still want to open an intent use:

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="intent:*"/>
```